# How to create inverse of scrubbing script in SED?

Tags: regex, sed

I wrote an SED script that deletes rows ("/d") that match a set of IP regular expressions. Now I want to re-read the same source file and create the inverse output - delete anything that is not in that list.

If I just throw a "!" expression, it will delete everything since they will all match the "not" condition of all the other IP list entries.

Here's the example of my regex in internal.lst:

```
/10\.10\.50\.0/d
/10\.100\.0\.0/d
/10\.101\.0\.0/d
/10\.101\.0\.128/d
```

And an example of the SED execution (in a .bat file):

```
for /f %%f IN ('dir /b source\*.txt') do (
  sed -f ..\internal.lst staging\%%f > scrubbed\external\%%f
  REM some inverse of above line!!!!   >scrubbed\internal\%%f
move staging\%%f scrubbed\original

    )
```

**EDIT:**
To confirm that I understand bobbogo's comment, I'd do something like:

```
sed -f list.lst staging\in.txt > out.txt
```

and I'll put in the list.lst file:

```
/10\.100\.0\.0{p;n}
/10\.101\.0\.0{p;n}
/10\.101\.0\.128{p;n}
```

is that right?

Comment: Can't you just combine your list of matching expressions into a single expression with or operators, and _then_ use the inversion operator (`!`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), the `-n` option suppresses the automatic printing of the pattern space, which allows you to use the `p` command to print select lines:

```
$ cat in.txt 
10.101.0.128
10.101.0.133
10.101.0.11
$ sed -n '/10\.10\.50\.0/p
/10\.100\.0\.0/p
/10\.101\.0\.0/p
/10\.101\.0\.128/p' in.txt
10.101.0.128
```

EDIT:

Note that this approach will produce duplicates if an input line can match with more than one expressions:

```
$ cat in.txt 
10.101.0.0
10.101.0.128
10.101.0.133
10.101.0.11
$ sed -n '/10\.10\.50\.0/p
/10\.100\.0\.0/p
/10\.101\.0\.0/p
/10\.101\.0\.128/p
/10\.101\.0\.[0-9]$/p' in.txt
10.101.0.0
10.101.0.0
10.101.0.128
```

To deal with this, you can use the `p` command, followed by the `d` command:

```
$ sed -n '/10\.10\.50\.0/{p; d}
/10\.100\.0\.0/{p; d}
/10\.101\.0\.0/{p; d}
/10\.101\.0\.128/{p; d}
/10\.101\.0\.[0-9]$/{p; d}' in.txt
10.101.0.0
10.101.0.128
```

EDIT:

As per the comment by [bobbogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470195/bobbogo), you can use the `n` command instead of `d`.

Comment: Again, you may wish to replace the `p` in the script with `{ p; n }` to avoid duplicates in the output.

Comment: bobbogo: see edit (can't format in comments properly) to confirm my understanding of what you're saying

Answer (score 2):

You used the 'd' command. Now use the 'p' command, combined with -n flag (-n to not output not-matching rows, p to print matching ones)

Comment: This scheme may output duplicates

Comment: True, but he did not ask to delete duplicates :-)

Comment: Are we saying that duplicates will be created, or that duplicate entries that aleady existed in the source file will be preserved?